# C program not display expected result

Tags: c

I have the following code which does not give the result that I thought it would. When I run the program it does not display anything after I enter the SIN number:
I want the program to tell me that the SIN number I enter is valid, but it just exits without showing the result!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,total_sum,num11,sin_num[9];
    int digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4,digit5,digit6,digit7,digit8,digit9,digit10,digit11,digit12,digit13;
    int digit14,num12,num13,num14;
    printf("SIN Validator \n");
    printf("============= \n");

    for(num1=0;num1<9;num1++) {
            printf("Enter your SIN one by one:");
            scanf("%d", &sin_num[num1]);
    }

    num2 = sin_num[0] * 1;
    num3 = sin_num[1] * 2;
    num4 = sin_num[2] * 1;
    num5 = sin_num[3] * 2;
    num6 = sin_num[4] * 1;
    num7 = sin_num[5] * 2;
    num8 = sin_num[6] * 1;
    num9 = sin_num[7] * 2;
    num10 = sin_num[8] * 1;

    total_sum = num2+num3+num4+num5+num6,num7+num8+num9+num10;
    digit13 = total_sum % 10;

    digit1 = num3 % 10;
    digit2 = num3 / 10;
    digit3 = digit1 + digit2;
    digit4 = num5 % 10;
    digit5 = num5 / 10;
    digit6 = digit4 + digit5;
    digit7 = num7 % 10;
    digit8 = num7 / 10;
    digit9 = digit7 + digit8;
    digit10 = num9 % 10;
    digit11 = num9 / 10;
    digit12 = digit10 + digit11;

    num11 = num2+digit3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10;
    num12 = num2+digit3+num4+digit6+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10;
if (num3 >= 10 && num11 % 10 == 0 && num5 < 10 && num7 < 10 && num9 < 10) {
            printf("This is a valid SIN number");
    }

    if (num3 >= 10 && num5 >= 10 && num7 < 10 && num9 < 10 && num11 % 10 == 0 && num12 % 10) {
            printf("This is a valid SIN number");
    }

    //else if(num5 >

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?` Not using a debugger to find out what is going wrong...

Comment: 1) Not initializing your variables -1
2) Not commenting your code -1
3) No return value from main -1

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here

```
num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6, num7 + num8 + num9 + num10;
                           /*   ^ should be a `+' */
```

It's mainly caused by

1. Not having compiler warnings enabled.

   This syntax is valid but it has a special meaning, the first part of the sum is discarded and only from `num7` and on it's result is stored at `total_sum`.
2. Having a bad programming style.

   1. Lack of whitespace surrounding operators.
   2. Declaring 9 `int` variables does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: That was a mistake, but it hasn't fixed the issue. I commented the second if statement and found that the first if statement works if all conditions are met. I did the same for second if statement and same thing happened. I think I am doing something wrong with if statements.

Comment: @HassenFatima Your solution is unnecessarily complicated, can you please explain what rules must the SIN satisfy in order for it to be valid?

Comment: SIN must be 9 digits long, but we can assume user enters the correct length, so we don't need to check that. We need to multiply them by 121 212 121 and the answers of that must add to number that can be evenly divisible by 10 with remainder 0

Comment: @HassenFatima I still don't understand.

Comment: Lets say if SIN number is 123456789 we must multiply them with 121212121, so 1*1, 2*2, 3*1 and so on. then we must add the total of the multiplied number and use mod(%) operator to find the final answer. If mod return 0 the SIN number is valid else no. Thanks

Comment: @Hassen Do you know how to debug? If not, why not? If so, what does debugging tell you? There's a far bigger picture here. Your real problem is not that your program doesn't work, rather that you haven't yet learnt how to troubleshoot such a problem. Make that your next priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
From after the line `num10 = sin_num[8] * 1;`, replace your code with:

```
num3 = num3%10 + num3/10;
num5 = num5%10 + num5/10;
num7 = num7%10 + num7/10;
num9 = num9%10 + num9/10;
total_sum = num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10; // your old total_sum line
if (total_sum%10==0) printf("This is a valid SIN number");
} /*close bracket for main
```

Although the thing above can fix your program, your whole program can be rewritten to something else extremely simple.
Your code is too complicated.
I guess you did not know you can change the value of a variable like this `num9 = num9%10 + num9/10;` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to use arrays and it would be better to have numbering according to intention. So num2 is bad choice for 1. element (#0).
You check doubled values if remained under 10 and then check corrected sum if divisible by 10. As iharob has pointed out: sum has a `,` instead of `+` in your code. I assumed that your last condition `&& num12 % 10` is intented to be `0 == ( num12 % 10 )`.

**Update:**
I checked [SIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Insurance_Number) calculation and your approach is far from that. Here is one:

```
const uint ND = 9;
/* .. */
for( int idx = 0; idx < ND ); ++idx )
{
    printf( "Enter your SIN one by one (#%d): ", idx );
    scanf( "%d", &num[idx]);
    if( ( num[idx] < 0 ) || ( 10 <= num[idx] ) ) { valid = 0; idx = ND; }
    else
    {
        if( 1 & idx ) { num[idx] <<= 1; } // double every second
        if( 10 <= num[idx] ) { num[idx] -= ( 10 - 1 ) * ( num[idx] / 10 ); }
        sum += num[idx];
    }
}
if( valid && ( 0 != ( sum % 10 ) ) ) { printf( "This is a valid SIN number\n" ); }
```

**Code in question after refactoring** without knowing what is SIN for:

```
int num[9];
int valid = 1;
int sum   = 0;
printf( "SIN Validator \n" );
printf( "============= \n" );
for( int idx = 0; idx < sizeof( num ) / sizeof( sin_num[0] ); ++idx )
{
    printf( "Enter your SIN one by one (#%d): ", idx );
    scanf( "%d", &num[idx]);
    if( 1 & idx ) { num[idx] <<= 1; } // double every second
    sum += num[idx];
}
if( ( num[1] < 10 )
 || ( num[5] < 10 )
 || ( num[7] < 10 ) ) { valid = 0; }

if( valid && ( 0 != ( sum % 10 ) ) ) { valid = 0; }

if( valid && ( 10 <= num[3] ) )
{
    sum -= ( 10 - 1 ) * ( num[3] / 10 );
    if( 0 != ( sum % 10 ) ) { valid = 0; }
}

if( valid ) { printf( "This is a valid SIN number\n" ); }
```